# Errors running bash script from pandoc filters repo in WSL

Tags: sh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, pandoc

I'm trying to run `runtests.sh` from [this](https://github.com/pandoc/lua-filters) repo on my local machine using WSL. First I installed WSL using `wsl --install Ubuntu`. Then I navigated to my local clone and ran `sh runtests.sh`. I got the following error:

> : not found: 4:
>
> : not found: 7:
>
> runtests.sh: 8: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting "do")

I'm not too familiar with bash scripts, and I'm pretty sure this one should work, since it's part of a reasonably well maintained repo. There has got to be something wrong with how I'm calling the script.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you attempting to run a shell script with CRLF line endings?

Use `file runtests.sh` to confirm.

git will checkout files using CRLF line endings on windows if `core.autocrlf` is `true`.

Use `git config core.autocrlf` to confirm.

To disable this behavior and reset your working directory:

```bash
git config core.autocrlf false
git checkout -- . # CAVEAT: This will overwrite working directory changes <>
```

Comment: That was the problem. I ran the commands and now I'm not getting the error anymore.

Comment: Regarding your edit, I ran it from WSL2 and it was fine. Not sure I want to change the CRLF defaults on the cloning machine. Isn't CRLF the default in Windows?

Comment: git config is scoped either locally (repo-level, default), or at the user or system level . This can get complicated if a non-local config setting is different on either your windows versus linux git client. Because this is a linux repo, disabling autocrlf should be fine; most windows editors (like vscode) will handle this by default. it is only in specific cases like executing windows batch files where this could become a problem.

Comment: Ah I see. Well I made sure to do `git config --local core.autocrlf false` so I'm limiting any potential problems to this repo only.

Comment: That's ideal and client-agnostic (config entries are embedded in the repo through the `.git/config` file)